# Firebase Push Notification appears and disappears after few seconds from lockscreen and top notification bar

Tags: java, android, firebase, notifications, firebase-notifications

I was developing an app that receives Firebase push notification from my server. However this issue happens inconsistently, I may receive the notification and stay displaying it or sometimes disappears from Lock Screen and Top Notification Bar after a few seconds.

Below is my display notification after Firebase onMessageReceived code:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Resources res = this.getResources();

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_timer_icon)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_timer_icon))
                .setContentTitle("Firebase Notification")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setPriority(1)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        Notification noti = notification.build();
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
  <service android:name=".FirebaseNotificationService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".FirebaseIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

All I want is the notification stay displaying like Whatsapp messages appear on lockscreen and top notification bar which only disappear when user click on it. Any solution?

***I also called a service which will run AsyncTask in another class to call a web service right after my app display the notification. So far, this has run successfully when app is in foreground and background. Do you think this might affect the notification?

Comment: `NotificationCompat.Builder.setAutoCancel(true)` do you touch the notification before it disappears

Comment: @Lonergan6275 No, I just left it there. I was testing the maximum message length that can be displayed on my screen, however at some point it disappears after few seconds regardless.

Comment: As per your requirement, you only need to set "setAutoCancel(true)" and setContentIntent(pendingIntent) with your notification builder. Please try that by avoiding other options like setOngoing and setPriority.

Comment: @FebiMathew 
I also called a service which will run AsyncTask in another class to call a web service right after my app display the notification. So far, this has run successfully when app is in foreground and background. Do you think this might affect the notification?

Comment: No, i think. As far as you have setAutoCancel and contentIntent.

Comment: what device u r using to test?

Comment: @keshav  my device is OPPO F1s

Comment: @FebiMathew I just tried leaving my notification on lock screen without touching it, it displayed for a few minutes and my app running on background of my OPPO F1s due to China Phone issues with killing services if app closed. After that, the notification disappeared and my app is no longer running in the background.

Comment: @GhLiew I think that is acceptable behavior, if app will be killed/Force stop .

Comment: @keshav But how is it possible for Whatsapp message notifications to stay until user touches or view it?